# React Native+ TextInput inside flatlist's item+ scrolls is lagging

Tags: react-native, textinput, flatlist

I am using Flatlist in that I have used textinput field. While I scroll flatlist , textinput is automatically focussed and scroll is lagging and not working smooth. If I scroll outside the textinputfield, scroll works smooth.

any solution?

Answer (score 1):

in Flatlist mention nestedScrollEnabled, it will handle scrolling for both